# No identifier specified for entity JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I am getting the following error while calling stored proc using JPA:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity
I am trying to call stored proc using JPA but getting the following error
```

My POJO looks as below . How to resolve the following error while calling stored proc using JPA

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "SP_proc",
                procedureName = "dbo.SP_proc",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm1", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm2", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm3", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm4", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm5", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "@parm6", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "@result", type = Integer.class)

                })
})
public class SomeRealEntity {  }
```

Comment: Every entity needs a primary key (`@Id`), and yours doesn't. So fix it. A stored procedure has nothing to do with that

Comment: should i remove `@Entity` can you please post how the POJO should look like

Comment: You shouldn't even have that POJO in the first place. What's the point of a class with no field and no method?